# SwiftUI - Views inside TabView jump after a second if TabView is nested in NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

### My setup

Entry point (ContentView):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            FirstView()
                .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

FirstView:

```
struct FirstView : View {
    var body : some View {
        NavigationLink(destination:
            SecondView()
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .navigationBarHidden(true)) {
                    Text("Fourth View")
        }
    }
}
```

SecondView:

```
struct SecondView : View {
    var body : some View {
        TabView {
            FirstTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "play.circle.fill")
                    Text("First Tab")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("First Tab")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
            SecondTabView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                    Text("Second Tab")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Second Tab")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

FirstTabView

```
struct FirstTabView : View {
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Spacer()
                Text("FIRST")
                Spacer()
                Text("SECOND")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.all)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .border(Color.red, width: 5)
    }
}
```

And SecondTabView is very similar to the first one so I won't include it.

### The issue

The issue I am having right now is that the content of my TabViews jump up ignoring safe areas (For clarification see the attached screenshots). The view actually displays perfectly fine and as expected for a brief moment and then immediately jumps up breaking  everything.

I have found that this is only happening if the TabView is loaded via NavigationLink as I do right now. If I directly load the SecondView() inside my NavigationView on ContentView (or in other words its the first view that I load) then the issue is gone and everything works as expected.

I am sorry that I wasn't able to include GIF of the problem - the View starts off as the expected result and then after a seconds jumps up and becomes what you see on the actual result.

### Expected Result

[image: expected result]

### Actual Result

[image: actual result]

NOTE: On iPhones with notch my text is not even visible. Also I've put thick border in order to make my point more clear.

### EDIT

I just found out that locking the device and then unlocking it brings the screen back to normal.

Comment: Works as expected in Xcode 11.5, SwiftUI 1.0, Swift 5.2.4, iOS 13. Tested on iPhone 11 Pro (with a notch).

Comment: This code also works fine in XCode 12 SwiftUI 2.0

Comment: The code fails on both my physical device (iPhone 11) and my emulator. I am using the same setup as you  @pawello2222 . Are you sure you are loading the SecondView via NavigationLink as I am doing?

Comment: In order to see the TabView you have to go through the NavigationLink, if you directly load the TabView it works as expected for me too. @LualdiDylan

Comment: @DI.dev Yes, I copied your code without any modifications (just added a SecondTabView with the same code as FirstTabView). Works as expected. It might not work for you because of some other code you didn't show us (eg. in your images there is a *third* tab as well).

Comment: @pawello2222 Can't be the case because even when I copy my own code from this post it just doesn't work for me